# Prevent secondary node from pushing changes made to its own copy of the data to the primary node

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set

I have created a replica of 3 nodes where 1 node is primary and another 2 are secondary. I have assigned lower priority to the secondary nodes than the primary node.

I want the ability where changes made in the secondary node should not be synchronized with the primary node, but changes made in the primary node should be synchronized with the secondary nodes.

I do not want the connection to be bidirectional. Please find the rs.status() which I did below to implement this case but somehow changes made in the secondary are also getting synchronized with the primary. I do not want these changes to reflect in the Primary node.

```
"members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "localhost:27018",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    ....
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    ....
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "localhost:27020",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    .....
                    "syncSourceHost" : "localhost:27018",
                    .....
            }
    ]
```

And it's priority status is configured like below.

```
 "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "localhost:27018",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 2,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "localhost:27020",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 0,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            }
    ]
```

Moreover, I can also create two different standalone databases to implement this case, but I also want to track any updates that happen in both databases(This approach will take a lot of manual coding, which I won't prefer). Like any collection is updated, or deleted in the primary I want to sync this with the Secondary database. But if any changes happen in the secondary database I wanted to compare updated collections with collections present in the primary database. And I do not want to sync in this case, but I just want to show the difference between existing collections in both databases.

In the end, I want to track down the difference between the primary node and secondary nodes. Collections that are new in secondary nodes than primary node should be displayed.

Comment: What do you mean by "changes"? Definitionally replication is one way (from the node in PRIMARY state to the node(s) in SECONDARY) state. You cannot write data to a SECONDARY

Comment: if I am updating the existing collection in secondary through nodejs API, these changes are reflected in the primary node too. Even though priority of secondary node is low, how the data from a secondary node is synchronizing with the primary node? Configurations mentioned in above post are wrong? Primary node should not reflect changes made in secondary node

Comment: You cannot update the collection via the SECONDARY, it will return a 'not PRIMARY' error or something along those lines. I would double check how you are performing your testing. To your original request, perhaps the [cluster-to-cluster sync tool](https://www.mongodb.com/products/cluster-to-cluster-sync) would do what you need

Comment: The scenario which I am expecting, is it doable with a replica? or can you suggest me a different solution? In my scenario, I am not getting any errors while writing to SECONDARY. I have provided my basic configurations above for reference too.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a replica of 2 nodes

This is the first mistake. Add at least an arbiter. Please read why number of members shouldn't be even https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/

> I am updating the existing collection in secondary

No, you are not. Only primary accepts write operations. Please read how replica set works https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/. Nodejs Mongodb driver is aware about database topology. It keeps connections to all members of the replica, checks which one is current primary and send all insert, update, and delete operations to this node exclusively.
By default, it reads from the primary too.

Saying that, mongo can initiate re-election of the primary, and considering you have only 2 members in the replica, it might happen more often than necessary. The process is called failover.

Nodejs driver is smart enough to detect if clientside topology is not up to date, and handle exceptions of accidental write attempts to a secondary node that just stepped down from primary. It actualises inforamtion about new db topology and repeats the write operation to the new primary. These errors are not exposed to the application level unless the cluster fails to elect new primary, e.g. when majority of nodes are down.

**UPDATE** for [2nd edition of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75025971/2):

> In the end, I want to track down the difference between the primary node and secondary nodes.

I'm afraid mongo is not designed to have differences between nodes, apart from natural replication latency or [intentionally delayed replica members](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/).
Any changes on secondary members which did not come from primary oplog will cause errors in replication.

The failover protocol is designed to make sure a secondary member can automatically step up as a primary at any time and keep the replica set operational with minimal data loss when the primary node become unreachable for any reason.

Comment: Can you suggest some different ways, to implement this approach then? I want to write on both nodes but synchronization should happen from primary to secondary, not the other way around. I am interested in keeping track of different collections between two databases in case of millions of records. Since MongoDB has change stream functionality, so I can keep track of updated documents and I do not need to write a manual check with some queries, so was checking to use replicas. If there is another approach then I am happy to read. Thank you

Comment: Also, I have tried the same scenario with two secondary nodes and one primary node. I know writing should only happen to the primary node. But if I am writing to one of the secondary nodes, then why it is replicating in the Primary node too? Or I should not use secondary node for writing explicitly? and make it as a standalone node?

Comment: It's not that you "should not use secondary for writing", it's more like you cannot use secondary for writing. Can you update the question with an example how you write to secondaries from nodejs application?  the simplest reproducible example. no business logic please. It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, and I believe it's just  a matter of misusing terminology or some confusion in how it works. If I get your comments you believe you are writing something to a secondary node, but it's not what  is happening on the wire.

Comment: Sure. I will update my question